# Save variables after closing jframe and re-opening in java

Tags: java, variables

I'm making a program that asks you to enter a password, and adds in an option to change the password later, but every time I close it and open it again, the password is reset to the default every time I open it again. I've set the default close operation to hide, but I think every time I run the program again, it's completely new. Also, I look into the background programs of my task manager, and there's a lot of "Java TM Platform SE Binary"s. 
Here's my core questions:

When I run a program from eclipse, does it open a brand new program every time? Can I change this?

How would I save variables across the open/close actions in my program?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post any code, so I'm going to assume you have a `password` variable defined and your program looks something like this:

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
String password = "Default01";
System.out.print("Enter new password: ");
password = userInput.next();
```

Each time you run the program, it will create in RAM, a brand new `password` variable instance.  When the program is closed, anything in RAM is destroyed.  You need some sort of persistent storage where you are writing that information to a variable.  A text file is an easy way to start.  Adding that would make your program look like:

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
File passwordFile = new File("passwordfile.txt");
//this is where the password is stored.
Scanner passwordScanner = new Scanner(passwordFile);
//this is how you read the file.
String password = passwordScanner.next();
//password has been read.
```

... Then prompt for a new password.

```
System.out.print("Enter new password: ");
password = userInput.next(); //prompt for new password
```

... Then write that new password to a file for persistent storage.

```
PrintWriter passwordWriter = new PrintWriter("passwordfile.txt");
// overwrites the current passwordfile.txt, so you now have an empty file
passwordWriter.print(password);
//writes the password to passwordfile.txt so it can be used next time.
```

Hopefully that helps a bit!

Answer (score 0):

Running the program again will start it in a fresh state, so anything stored in variables the previous run will be gone. If you want to persist data, you will need to have you program store it in a file or database (file would be easiest to learn as a beginner). Then, when you run the program again, you would have it check if the saved file exists, open it, and read in the saved password. There are lots of tutorials on how to do file input/output in Java, so just search Google for one.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing variables to text file or `Serialize` them. If you want to make it harder, then just use a database of your choice.